# How to capture high resolution image on Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, image-capture

I would like to capture high resolution image with Windows Mobile device. I've tried the example from WM SDK, but it captures just a single frame of video camera and the resolution is poor.
Has anyone any experience with image capturing on Pocket PC with C++?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the filter used by the example code to capture a high-resolution image.  When you use the viewfinder in a digital camera, the camera "simulates" a video camera look by applying the lowest resolution filter and then rapidly taking and displaying single frames.  When you click the button to take a high-res picture, the camera has to swap out the low-res filter for the high-res filter and then take the high-res picture - this is why (cheap) digital cameras always take so long to snap a picture.

I don't know which code example you're working with, but if it's the one I used it defaults to using the lowest resolution filter.  There should be a line in it somewhere that selects the filter.  You just need to change the value passed from 0 to (probably) 3 or 4 for the highest resolution.