# Windows Mobile / Directdraw: Rotate video stream

Tags: windows-mobile, rotation, video-capture, directdraw

Follow up from: [Directdraw: Rotate video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289637/windows-mobile-directdraw-display-video-stream-take-picture)

I managed to preview the camera's video stream, but the image is rotated by 90° to landscape mode. I'm now searching for a way to rotate the camera image back to normal, but the problem is I don't even know where to start: Is this done in the VideoCaptureFilter, the VideoInfoHeader, in a DDSURFACEDESC structure? Can the rotation only be done by using an additional filter? Is it a filter setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is usually done with the BI_SRCPREROTATE flag:

> A special flag was developed
>   (BI_SRCPREROTATE) which tells GDI and
>   the video renderer that the
>   orientation of the image from the
>   camera is in the correct orientation
>   (don't rotate when rendering it). This
>   is necessary because as you rotate the
>   shell on the device you also
>   physically rotate the device. When the
>   display driver rotates bitmaps to
>   render the shell and UI it needs to
>   know that this particular bitmap
>   shouldn't be rotated. The flag is or'd
>   into the biCompression field in the
>   BITMAPINFO structure.

From http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/PocketPC/microsoft.public.pocketpc.developer/2005-12/msg00850.html

Sample code might look like this:

```
  pVih->bmiHeader.biCompression &= ~BI_SRCPREROTATE;
```

From http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/bbs/discussion/view.do?parentCategoryId=4&messageId=45549&boardId=224&platformId=2

This method however is not working with the HTC HD2 I am using, but it might work with other devices, so I decided to add this to my question.